# Get data from database in array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM servers;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$datas = array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)) {
        $datas[]= $row;
    }
}
```

This is what the `$datas` array looks like:

[image: this is how my array looks like]

I use the following code and this is what i get:

This is what I want it to look like:

[image: this is how i want my array to look like]

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options - remove the `id` column from the `SELECT` i.e.

```
$sql = "SELECT type, host FROM servers";
```

If you make this change you can simplify the data reading to

```
$datas = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Or you can add only the `type` and `host` value into the `$datas` array:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)) {
    $datas[]= array('type' => $row['type'], 'host' => $row['host']);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the loop? It seems to be doing nothing useful at all. You can do that with `fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`, right?

Comment: @Dharman if the query is changed, then you're right. I've edited.